# Symfony2 one form for many entities Many To One relation

Tags: php, forms, symfony, controller, entity

I really need help with form issue.
I have main Entity - user:

```
class User {
private $id;
private $name;
private $surname;
private $description;
private $photo;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Adress", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $adresses;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Groups", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups")
 */
private $groups;
```

I have all get, set, __construct etc...

Then Address Entity:

```
class Adress {
private $id;
private $city;
private $street;
private $number;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="adresses", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

And form for Adress:

```
class AdressType extends AbstractType {
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('city')
            ->add('street')
            ->add('number')
            ->add('user')
    ;
}
```

etc.. (generate by CRUD)

And form for User:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('surname')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('photo', 'file', array('label' => 'Photo (files: .jpg, .png)', 'data_class' => null))
            ->add('groups')
            ->add('adresses', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AdressType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
            ))
```

Controller for new User:

```
    private function createCreateForm(User $entity) {

    $adress = new Adress();
    $entity->addAdress($adress);

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}
   public function createAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new User();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        //add Photo
        /**
         * @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file 
         */
        $photo = $entity->getPhoto();

        //generate name for photo
        $photoName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $photo->guessExtension();

        $photo->move($this->getParameter('photo_directory'), $photoName);

        $entity->setPhoto($photoName);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

The results look like this: 
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVnVi.png)
I don't know how to solve th problem I would like to add information from two entities (User, Adress) in one form. But I don't know what I should do with the 'user' in AdressType - because it shows as select field but I want to add new relation between this adress and this user.

Can anyone help me - I spend few hours and can't figure out. :) thank you!

Comment: Well, I think that you should just read this [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#advanced-example-with-objects) about choice fields in forms and you'll be able to solve your problem)

Comment: Ok than you.... But I don't want make a choice Field. I want to add new user with new adress and here I need to choose to with user this address will be assigment... but I am creating new user and he dosen't exist in db yet ...